# Live Editing - Web Socket connection failed in Genexus 18

Tags: genexus

I wanted to ask a question about Live Editing in GX18. The service connects correctly, but the changes are not reflected in the browser. I noticed that the console shows the connection as Failed.

I haven't found information on the web about this specific topic, but I tested port 30100 on my localhost with `netstat -at`, and the port is listening correctly. The issue seems to be only with the browser

Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you check if you have the 'WebSocket protocol' enabled in the Windows features?